# How to adjust tabular width to math body as defined by geometry?

Tags: tables, geometry

How to adjust `tabular` width to math body as defined by `geometry`? In the following example the table goes more to the right than the border of body as defined by `geometry` package.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{|p{0.3\linewidth}|p{0.7\linewidth}|}
    \hline
    \lipsum[2] & \lipsum[2]\\\hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's a weird table. Do you simply want the text to be formatted like that? In that case, there are better options.

Comment: @Alenanno no, that's just a minimal example. I have to reproduce a layout made by MS word, especially a table.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see from your image: there is space between your columns, each column has \tabcolsep either side so your table is

```
\textwidth+4\tabcolsep
```

if you had array package loaded then rules would take width and it would be

```
\textwidth+4\tabcolsep+3\arrayrulewidth
```

so use

```
\dimen0=\textwidth-4\tabcolsep

\begin{tabular}{|p{.3\dimen0}|p{.7\dimen0}|}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to account for the fact that the table possesses three vertical bars (each of width `\arrayrulewidth`) and that each column has whitespace-padding on the left and right (in the amount of `\tabcolsep`).

You can either adjust the column widths manually, as is done in the first example below, or employ the `tabularx` package and set up the `tabularx` environment to have columns of relative widths 0.3 and 0.7. (Since there are two columns, the sums of the `\hsize` macros have to sum to 2.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe,vmargin=1cm]{geometry} % make both tables fit on one page
\usepackage{lipsum,tabularx}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|
  p{\dimexpr0.3\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth\relax}|
  p{\dimexpr0.7\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}
  \hline
  \lipsum[2] & \lipsum[2]\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|
  >{\hsize=0.6\hsize}X|
  >{\hsize=1.4\hsize}X|}
  \hline
  \lipsum[2] & \lipsum[2]\\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `tabularx` package implicitly performs the calculation shown in David's answer, i.e., `\dimen0=\dimexpr\textwidth-4\tabcolsep-3\arrayrulewidth\relax`. The code shown above then sets the column widths to `0.3\dimen0` and `0.7\dimen0`, respectively.

Comment: note that tabularx loaded array so changed the width of the table: vertical rules take up no horizontal space in the original latex implementation.